# What are the various zones of the map that I need to swap between to change my Warp and Save Rooms in the Randomizer?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

I found a Warp Room on the Galleon Minerva, then died before saving and went back to it, and found a Save Room there instead. Then, when I went back to the Galleon Minerva from Arantville, the Save Room that was previously a Warp Room, was now a Warp Room again, which I could use to travel back to Arantville and save, whereupon reloading, the Galleon Minerva Warp Room could not be used again, since it presumably is a Save Room again?

If I want to get more Warp Rooms in what appears to be the Arantville / Castle zone, it seems I can go to the Galleon Minerva, save, reload and check out the "Castle" zone map again to see if any Saves turned into Warps? The other zones that can cause a re-shuffle of Save / Warp Room states are the Bridge of Evil, and the post-Gebel area(s), right? Is there anywhere else I should make sure I'm prepared to possibly lose my warps / save rooms before going in?

Also apparently the Gebel boss room? Since I went in, and died multiple times, with one time having turned the save point I respawned in, into a warp room instead.